# PHP sessions in HTACCESS - timeout

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I'm debugging a infinite loop problem in PHP in my "logout" routine.

```
if($_SESSION)
{
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
sleep(1);
header('7location: http://accounts.DOMAIN.com/');
exit;
```

in my main / initial.inc.php script i have :-

```
$sess=0;
$sess=$_SESSION['loggedin'];
foreach($_SESSION as $asw => $asd)
{
    $logrep.="SESSW '$asw' '$asd'\n";
}

if($sess>0)
{
    if($sess<$ty)
    {
        $logrep.="is timed out - logging out\n";
        header('Location: http://accounts.DOMAIN.com/logout/');
        exit;
```

Theres a bit more code which i've taken out - but in my 'logout' script Ive got DESTROY / UNSET etc -

but when it redirects to my inward script, my sessions STILL EXIST ? - & then it determines i'm timed out, & redirects to my logout routine.

QUERY: is there a fool-proof way to remove / eliminate ALL sessions ?

QUERY :-

```
$previous_name = session_name("NAME");
session_save_path("$directory");
session_start();
```

Is there a php.ini line i can use, to replace  session_name  so that all/any PHP scripts are using the same name ? (just in case there are some scripts not using the named session.)

EDIT :-

If i use

```
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
```

will it destroy *ALL* sessions ? or just the currently-named one ? (I suspect some of my scripts aren't using the named session)

Ps - scripts are in different directories / subdomains.

EDIT 2 :-

Ive now chanmged my script to :-

```
     $sess=0;
     $logrep.="SESS NOW '$sess'\n";
     $logrep.=var_dump( $sess=$_SESSION['loggedin']);
     $logrep.="SESSNOW2 - '$sess'\n\n\n";
     $text.="Logged in time $sess\n";
     $logrep.="\nSESS = $sess\n";
     $temp2=time();
     $temp1=($sess-$temp2);
     $logrep.="IFF SESS $sess > TIME $time - TEMP $temp1\n";
     if($sess>0)
     {
       - redirect to log out routine ....
```

(some code removed)

RESULT :-

```
    OLD SESS - '1391680203'
    SESS NOW '0'
    SESSNOW2 - '1391680203'
```

Apparently, my sessions are NOT being deleted / removed.

Comment: are you trying to destroy sessions for all users?

Comment: just the named user - Not all users (the user that logged out).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your file 'initial.inc.php' is included in the top of every scripts.

On your logged out page, you have :

session_unset();
session_destroy();

At this stage, your session is destroyed. Then you do

header('location: http://accounts.DOMAIN.com/');

Which executes 'initial.inc.php';

I assume that you have at the start of initial.inc.php 'session_start();, because you have

```
$sess=$_SESSION['loggedin'];
```

And it doesn't seems it throws a warning because of the session being missing. So your session is re-created in your initial.inc.php file.

Comment: Yes - initial.inc.php is called at the start of every call. My sripts seem to be Ok logging in & using the scripts, but only causes the loop on log-out.

Comment: Can you please log the output of 
var-dump( $sess=$_SESSION['loggedin'] ) afer the first logout redirection? It seems it is >0, while it should be == null, right?

Comment: Ive now changed my script to :-
         $sess=0;
         $logrep.="SESS NOW '$sess'\n";
         $logrep.=var_dump( $sess=$_SESSION['loggedin']);
         $logrep.="SESSNOW2 - '$sess'\n\n\n";
         $text.="Logged in time $sess\n";
         $logrep.="\nSESS = $sess\n";
         $temp2=time();
         $temp1=($sess-$temp2);
         $logrep.="IFF SESS $sess > TIME $time - TEMP $temp1\n";
if($sess>0)
{
 - redirect to log out routine .... 
 (some code removed)
 RESULT :-
 

OLD SESS - '1391680203'
SESS NOW '0'
SESSNOW2 - '1391680203'

Apparently, my sessions are NOT being deleted / removed.

Comment: See EDIT2.   I do not geta nything extra in my LOG, but at the top of my visable screen, I get lots of "int(1391680203)" - which is the current time (i think ?)

Comment: try $_SESSION['loggedin']=0 in your logged - out script. This should temporarly fix your issue. I'll try to reproduce this tomorow.

Comment: Ive now solved my endless loop. (GOOD). HOWEVER, I can't log out. Sessions still exist.

Comment: $_SESSION['loggedin']=0, session_unset, unset(session - loop), sessioN_destroy _ Nothing works, i'm still logged in. - ive also posted on the forum of my ISP/host of my website

Comment: FIXED. I've moved the routine to set/create the session path, ID etc into its own session.inc.php file & called it from the login & logout scripts.  ALTHOUGH i am sure both scripyts had the same info anyway. puttong into its own file works. i can now login & out.